# Save Power BI report with offline data

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report that uses a DirectQuery connection to an on-premise database.  Without having to install a Power BI gateway is it possible to save the report to include a static copy of the data so that it can be published?

The idea here is to be able to open the report with the latest data, then save an offline version then publish it so that it would contain all the data needed to be viewed on a shared workspace?

EDIT:
I just realized that you can convert your connection from DirectQuery to Import from the status bar in the bottom right of Power BI desktop.  As this is a one-way conversion it's not ideal but in theory, I could keep saving copies and convert them before publishing.  Would still love to know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a way to publish your report directly with offline data from a DirectQuery connection.  However, as I mentioned in my post you can save a copy of the report and permanently change the connection type.  It's a workaround and not a full solution but it does work.